# Suddenly Can't Run my app on real device,failed with exit code 6

Tags: certificate, device, xcode6.1

For some reason I'm getting this error when i'm trying to run my applications on my iPhone 6 Plus.

```
Command /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/swift-stdlib-tool failed with exit code 6
```

when reading the error, between the lines, I can see this inside my error log:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Couldn't posix_spawn: error 1'*** First throw call stack:
```

this error happen in all of my applications, so I believe it's certificate problem.
currently i'm trying to run an empty project and i'm getting the same error,
what i've tried to do so far is:

- Delete the derived files, plus doing it manually
- Delete all my certificates from Apple.developer and recreate them (developer certificate, App ID and Provisioning profile).
- Delete all my keys from KeyChain and install them again.
- Restart my mac and of course my iphone.

after doing all of that i'm still getting this error and unable to run an empty project.
i'm lack of options and feeling lost, any suggestion ?

Answer (score 0):

After weeks of being stuck with this i found that this kind of error means you mess up, somehow, your code sign file(system file).
What you need to do is get back from some back up (time machine if you have one) or the best way is to reinstall your current OS X, that will surely fix your problem.